# Shell Script to change Jenkins build description picking bogus old description

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins

I have a shell script to remotely change the Jenkins build description. It uses Jenkins' RESTful API to return a JSON string that contains the old description. This allows me to  prepend or append the new description to the old description. For example, when we deploy to a QA or production machine, I put the deployment information in the build:

```
<font color="red"><b>deployed to PROD on foolb02-ext</b></font>
<font color="blue"><b>deployed to QA on barlb02QA-test</b></font>
```

The first line is the last deployment which was to a production machine. The second line was the first deployment which was to a QA.

The complete `description.sh` script and other similar scripts are located in [Github](https://github.com/qazwart/jenkins-scripts).

I noticed when I have my script to change the description as part of my deployment script, and the old build description is blank, I was getting this:

```
<font color="blue"><b>deployed to QA on barlb02QA-test</b></font>
{"description":null}
```

I traced that `{"description":null}` to me using the RESTful API for the build to fetch the old blank description:

```
old_description=$(curl -s --user "$USER:$PASSWORD" --data "tree=description" \
    "$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/api/json")
```

When I run my `description.sh` script by itself, and the description is blank, the above syntax will set `$old_description` as:

```
 {"description":""}
```

And, I parse this to strip off the JSON stuff syntax:

```
old_description=${old_description#*:\"} #Remove JSON garbage
old_description=${old_description%\"\}} #Remove JSON garbage
```

However, when I run my `description.sh` script inside another shell script (like my deploy.sh script), `$old_description` is set as this:

```
 {"description":null}
```

and my parsing syntax doesn't affect this.

I can change my `description.sh` script to handle this, but what I'm really curious about is why the Jenkins API *seems* to be returning two different results depending whether or not I'm running my shell script in another script or not.

Comment: I always see the 'null' result for descriptions that haven't been set (Jenkins 1.517). Just guessing here, but perhaps the difference is 'null' is used for unset descriptions and "" is for a description that had a value that was cleared.

Comment: @DaveBacher - Yup, that's exactly what it is. Make it an official answer, and I'll accept it. When I test my `deployment.sh` script, I'm constantly setting and unsetting the description. When I do the deployment, the description was never set in the first place. I thought it had something to do with my `deploy.sh` script running my `description.sh` script, but it was merely an artifact of my testing and not some strange side-effect from the 25th dimension that was able to mysteriously sense how I was running the script. It's amazing how long you spend debugging piddling things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always see the `null` result for descriptions that haven't been set (in Jenkins 1.517). The difference that @DavidW sees is that `null` is used for unset descriptions and `""` (the empty string) is used for a description that had a value that was cleared.